# Parsing string via regex

Tags: linux, regex

How to parse the string output

```
5 Secs ( 2.2889%) 60 Secs ( 2.5874%) 300 Secs ( 2.6215%)
```

to take only **2.6215**

Answer (score 1):

Using grep and lookbehind/lookahead:

```
grep -Po "(?<=Secs \( )[0-9.]*(?=%\)$)"
```

Using sed:

```
sed 's/.*Secs ([[:space:]]*\([0-9.]*\)%)$/\1/g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using bash, something like this?

```
PATTERN="(\d+\.\d{4})%\)$"
if [[ "${VALUE}" =~ ${PATTERN} ]] ; then 
   VALUE="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```

Reworked from this [Stack Overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1891797/capturing-groups-from-a-grep-regex).

Answer (score 0):

Personally I'm a "keep it simple" kind of guy:

```
./command | awk '{print $12}' | sed 's/%)//'
```